# C++11 synchronisation in Linux signal handler

Tags: linux, c++11, signals

I have a multithreaded Linux app that is required to terminate smoothly in response to `SIGTERM`.

The way it's currently implemented uses a `std::promise<void>` and associated future: the main thread first installs a simple `SIGTERM` handler that sets the promise and returns, then it launches all the subsidiary threads, and then it waits on the future.  When `SIGTERM` is received, the handler sets the promise.  This unblocks the main thread, which controls orderly shutdown of the subsidiary threads and then exits.

This all works fine - but as far as I can tell there's actually no guarantee that it's safe to use `std::promise::set_value()` (or, for that matter, any other C++11 synchronisation mechanism) within the signal handler.

Is this actually risky in practice?  Should I replace this with e.g. `sem_post` or some other mechanism explicitly described as safe?